# Expression Engine: Removing Members From Mailing List

Tags: expressionengine, mailing-list

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it:

I have a site with an email newsletter signup form (uses EE's Mailing List module), as well as member registration.

If a user signs up for emails, and then later becomes a member, what is the best way to ensure that they don't receive duplicate emails, other than manually removing them from the email list?

Ideally, I'd want them to be removed from the email list when they confirm registration. Is there a direct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

ty

Comment: It would be awesome if you could support our proposal for a dedicated EE Stack Exchange site here (if you're already supporting it, you need to make sure your accounts are linked). http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine?referrer=AwnV9oYF5EKlETXKp3ZQQw2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.

I've just set up a test in my sandbox, and subscribed to the mailing list, and set up a member with the same email.  When I send a mail out, via the Communicate module, I do indeed get two copies.

Personally I think this is really a bug within EE, as ideally it should only send out to unique addresses.

I'm guessing that an extension for the http://expressionengine.com/developers/extension_hooks/member_member_register hook, to run a check against the Mailing List DB table?

Comment: An addon would be your best way to accomplish the removal. It would match on email address I suppose unless you are tracking conversions some other way.